# Working on a django project, webpage loads fine but datas are not fetching from PostgreSQL database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views, jinja2

I'm working on a django project and using PostgreSQL for database and when I run my webapp, it runs fine but it won't load up the datas from the database. Here are settings.py, models.py, views.py and the html file here. I've spent half of my day trying to fix this. I've no idea what went wrong. Plz help.

settings.py (PostgreSQL database)

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "app_name",
        'USER' : 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
    }
}
```

models.py

```
class Service(models.Model):
    index = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to="services_icons/")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.heading
```

views.py

```
def services_view(request):
    services = Service.objects.all().order_by("index"),
    return render(request, "service.html", {services : services})
```

service.html

```
        <div class="row">
            {% for item in services %}
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <i class="fa fa-3x text-primary mr-4"><img src="{{item.icon.url}}"></i>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                        <h4 class="font-weight-bold mb-3">{{item.heading}}</h4>
                        <p>{{item.description}}</p>
                        <a class="font-weight-semi-bold" href="">Read More <i
                                class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

I have tried manually deleting the database from the PostgreSQL using pgAdmin4 and re-migrating again.
I have also tried flushing the database.
`python manage.py flush`

Comment: try changing the engine to 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2' you also need to install package with 'pip install psycopg2-binary' it may resolve the issue
and also if you want to debug these kinds of problem I suggest using prints a lot like print serivces to see if there a any records in your database

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I tried changing the engine to 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2' and also installed 'pip install psycopg2-binary' and the issue is still not resolved. 
But as you mentioned I tried printing services and there it prints out the data fine. Why this is happening?

Comment: Dictionary key in your context should be a string. So, `return render(request, "service.html", {"services" : services}) `.

Comment: Thank you @mcpherson for this, now I can only see one "Read More>>" , the one inside the for loop. But why only one, because the for loop should've return multiple items.  and the datas are still not fetching.

Comment: @mcpherson @mohammadh-rzn 
After being stuck for hours in front of my screen, I find its because of the comma at the end of the query in the views.py file
 (`services = Service.objects.all().order_by("index"), `). 
After deleting the comma, it works fine. This is silly. Why this is happening? It'll be intuitive if it gives me an error.